# $[0,2\pi) \ni t \rightarrow e^{it} \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ |z|=1 \}$ is bijective

Tags: complex-analysis

Could you help me prove that $[0,2 \pi) \ni t \rightarrow e^{it} \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ |z|=1 \}$ is bijective?

It is fairly easy to prove that it is injective. I am having trouble proving surjectivity.

What we need to show is that on $[0,2\pi)$ the function has all the values on the circle $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \  x^2+y^2=1, \ x>0, \ y>0 \}$.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Surely you know that $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$ parametrizes the unit circle?

Comment: @Hagrid: btw, does "covering map" tell you something?

Comment: Also, the last condition on $x$ and $y$ is wrong, $e^{it}$ also attains values in other quadrants.

Comment: @mrf I think the point of the problem is to prove that $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ parametrizes the circle.

Comment: (Or maybe not, but the poster should really state what they are assuming as known.)

Comment: @Potato perhaps, but I have a hard time imagining anyone taking a class in complex analysis without knowing that fact from before.

Comment: @mrf The first time I saw a truly rigorous explanation of the connection between $e^{ix}$, $\pi$, and trigonometry was in Ahlfors' book, so maybe not?

Comment: Take any $z=x+i y$ with $\|z\|=1$. Then $x=\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\sin(\theta)$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Of course $z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be fixed. Then the points $t_1=2(n-1)\pi$ and $t_2=2n\pi$ are s.t.

$f(t_1)=\exp(i2n\pi-2\pi i)=(\exp(-2\pi i)=1)=\exp(i 2n\pi)=f(t_2)$,

denoting by $f$ the map s.t. $f(t)=exp(it)$. Then $f$ is not injective for $n\neq 1$.

If $n>1$ you are running along the circle more than once...you are covering it $n$-times.

Comment: I believe the $n$ was a typo; I've edited it out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

First: note that your conditions on $x$ and $y$ are wrong: does every point on the unit circle have positive $x$ and positive $y$?

The point here is that for real numbers $t$, $e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$. As $t$ ranges between $0$ and $2\pi$, $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ covers every point of the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$; can you use that to finish the problem?

Hint: Maybe come up with a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: I think the point of the problem is to prove that $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ parametrizes the circle.